# plot geom_point on top of boxplot from different data set

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset `a` from which I make a set of boxplots. On top of these boxplots I want to plot a `geom_point` which is just a subset of the original data set. The subset is stored in `b`.

What I am doing wrong to get this error?

```
ggplot(a, aes(x=reorder(miRNA,as.numeric(value)),y=as.numeric(value))) + geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(b, aes(x=reorder(miRNA,as.numeric(value)))) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text( angle = 90)) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-5, 5)) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 8) +
  labs(x = "miRNA", y = "log2 tumor/benign")
```

> Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval

```
> head(a)
             miRNA variable      value
2    hsa-let-7b-5p   ta.008 -0.1512121
3    hsa-let-7c-5p   ta.008 -0.2649810
11  hsa-miR-10a-5p   ta.008 -1.6736331
13  hsa-miR-122-5p   ta.008  0.0417420
15 hsa-miR-125a-5p   ta.008 -0.8262042
19  hsa-miR-128-3p   ta.008 -0.2867184
> head(b)
               miRNA variable     value
2670   hsa-let-7b-5p   tb1302  1.313482
2671   hsa-let-7c-5p   tb1302  1.071200
2679  hsa-miR-10a-5p   tb1302  1.728654
2681  hsa-miR-122-5p   tb1302  1.013428
2683 hsa-miR-125a-5p   tb1302 -0.274418
2687  hsa-miR-128-3p   tb1302 -4.967844
```

Comment: just use `data=b` instead of `b` in `geom_point()`

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is in your `aes()` specification to `geom_point()`.
You wrote:

`geom_point(b, aes(x=reorder(miRNA,as.numeric(value))))`

But I it should be:

`geom_point(b, aes(x=reorder(miRNA), y = as.numeric(value)))`

You shouldn't even need to re-specify the `aes()` in the call to `geom_point()` since it's the same as the overall plot.

Try it without subsetting the data - that is, plot all points - and see if that works.  I'd also suggest plotting all data and coloring or otherwise highlighting your subset instead; otherwise it may be confusing to people viewing the plot.

Note:
I usually specify `geom_boxplot(outlier.size = NA)` to suppress plotting of outliers when I'm overlaying points or the outliers wil be double-plotted